# React & RTK: How to dispatch from a middleware?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using RTK (Redux Toolkit) and RTK Query to manage my store and API requests.

To catch errors globally, I followed [this example](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/error-handling#handling-errors-at-a-macro-level). That works fine, but now I'd like to log out the user when a request was rejected because of a `401 - Unauthorized`-error.

```
const rtkQueryErrorLogger = api => next => action => {
  if (isRejectedWithValue(action)) {
    if (action.payload.status === 401) {
      // Reset the store (not working)
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const dipatch(logout());
  
      // Forward to login-screen (not working)
      const navigation = useNavigation();
      navigation.push('Login');
    }
  }
  return next(action);
};
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Redux middleware always gets a "mini-store API" object as the argument to the outermost function, which contains `{dispatch, getState}`:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#writing-custom-middleware

In this case, it's the variable named `api` in your example.

You can access `dispatch` from that object and dispatch an action at any time inside your middleware.  Just delete the `const dispatch = useDispatch` line, and either change the next line to `api.dispatch()` or destructure `dispatch` from the `api` object in the declaration.

Comment: So how can one redirect to login screen from this middleware?
Hooks cannot be used here.
Can I do this using NextJs Router?